# How to click a link inside a table in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a link inside a table

The code is

```
                <a href="https://www.gmailnator.com/briceschultztmp/messageid/#17b725237c535ef2">
                    <table class="message_container">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Discord <noreply@discord.com></noreply@discord.com></td>
                                <td>Verify Email Address for Discord</td>
                                <td class="text-right">13 minutes ago</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </a></td></tr></tbody>
```

I try this code

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a"))).click()
```

but its not clicking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this xpath :

```
//table[@class='message_container']/..
```

or

```
//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.gmailnator.com/briceschultztmp/messageid')]
```

and click it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.gmailnator.com/briceschultztmp/messageid')]"))).click()
```